# Dividing by a range values

Tags: matlab

I am a bit confused with the below output:

```
>> 1:6/3

    ans =

         1     2
```

But

```
>> 1/3

ans =

    0.3333
```

Also

```
>> 1:24/3

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

It seems like MATLAB is outputting only values of number divisible in range 1-24 by 3? But why not for those which are  not fully divisible by 3?

Also I am not able to understand the below output:

```
>> 1:24/3:2

    ans =

         1
```

Similarly

```
>> 1:6/2 * 2

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

Comment: Try to add parenthesis ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But what does output means in case no parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple enough:

`1:6/3` implies `1:2` which is a vector ranging from `1` to `2`.

`1/3` is simply a straight forward division.

`1:24/3` implies `1:8` which is a vector ranging from `1` to `8`.

`1:24/3:2` implies `1:8:2` which is a vector ranging from `1` to `2` with a difference of `8` between each element. This just leaves you with `1` as the next possible iteration, `9` would be greater than `2`.

`1:6/2 * 2` implies `1:3*2` which implies `1:6`. This is a vector ranging from `1` to `6`.

Comment: Thanks for explicit clarification

Comment: @RoneyMichael oye kunda :D

Answer (score 4):

This is an [operator precedence](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) problem. `/` has higher precedence level than `:`.

Therefore `1:6/3` is equivalent to `1:(6/3)`, while you wanted to compute `(1:6)/3`

Try with parenthesis to observe different results:

```
>> (1:6)/3
>> (1:24)/3
>> (1:24)/(3:2)
>> ((1:6)/2)*2
```

Comment: But what does output means in case no parenthesis? What does these division expand too without parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

You might be aware of the BODMAS rule which says that the

B   Brackets first

O   Orders (ie Powers and Square Roots, etc.)

DM  Division and Multiplication (left-to-right)

AS  Addition and Subtraction (left-to-right)

When modified to the usage in mathematics it added a few more operators according to which `/` has a higher precedence over `:`

Therefore you get erroneous results. You can check this thing by implementing more brackets.